# PHP Array Values Are Not Adding Together

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to parse through a .txt file using PHP. And as I go through the Array, I am trying to add indexes 2 and 3 together. The values print out when I do a simple print but, when adding them together they result in zero.

```
<?php
$inFile =  'inData2.txt';
$inData = file( $inFile ) or die( "Cannot open file=$inFile");

$totSales = 0;
$totItems = 0;
$firstLine=true;

foreach ( $inData as $ct => $line ){
    if( $firstLine ) {
        $firstLine=false;
        continue;   }

    $spLine = explode( ",", $line );

    $new = intval($spLine[2]) + intval($spLine[3]);
    print "$spLine[2] <br>";
    print "$spLine[3] <br>";
    print "$new <br>";

    $totSales += $spLine[2] * $spLine[3];
    $totItems += 1; }

print "<br /> totItems=$totItems TotSales=$totSales";
?>
```

The .txt file contains:

```
Part ,Description,Sales,PricePerUr,Year
B101,10 speed Bike,12,100,2015
B102,15 Speed Mountain,15,200,2015
B103,20 Speed Mountain,10,400,2015
B104,TriCycle,25,50,2016
```

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($spLine[2])` and `var_dump($spLine[3])` output to that script?

Comment: Everything is fine here. Where's is zero?

Comment: Copied ur code, got output `totItems=4 TotSales=9450`

Comment: 12
100
0
15
200
0
10
400
0
25
50
0

totItems=4 TotSales=0

Comment: When I go to print it out those are the numbers that display. So, the 0 after 12 and 100 should be 112 and so on.

Comment: Once again: your code runs __fine__ https://3v4l.org/K69sW Either your show us not relevant code or not relevant data.

Comment: Yeah, I see it running. Something might be wrong with my machine then, thank you. @u_mulder

Comment: @Oswald Please save the moderators a job and delete this question as it will not be helpful to future SO readers.